# TypeScript generic with conditional evaluates union types separately

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a TypeScript type that will represent either a `VoidFunction` or a function with a single parameter based on a provided generic.

Using a conditional, the type looks like this:

```
type VoidFunctionOrWithParams<Params> = Params extends void
    ? VoidFunction
    : (params: Params) => void;
```

An example usage might look like this:

```
type WithStringParams = VoidFunctionOrWithParams<'one' | 'two'>;
```

**Expected Result Type**

```
(params: 'one' | 'two') => void
```

**Actual Result Type**

```
((params: "one") => void) | ((params: "two") => void)
```

Why does TypeScript interpret this as two separate functions with no overlap? Is there a way around this? What I really want is *one* function type where `params` could be any of the values in the union - not different function types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of [conditional distributive types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) here. To *avoid* distribution, you can wrap the generic type in a *tuple*.

```
type VoidFunctionOrWithParams<Params> = [Params] extends [void]
    ? VoidFunction
    : (params: Params) => void;

type WithStringParams = VoidFunctionOrWithParams<'one' | 'two'>;
// type WithStringParams = (params: "one" | "two") => void
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAag9gSwCYDECuA7AxsBcMDyATgOoLAAWACgIZE0C2AzgDy33MB8UAvFANrtGTALpQIAD2AQMSJgIBuiJCIBQUDVAD8sZemy586zQC4oACjB1hZocwCUvbkuQBuVatCQoZSgGVgIgQMAHM7eT54ZH0cPEJScmprZhYAcnwIVKgAHyhU4AB3OFTOdwB6MqgvaF8KAKDQ8N4LKw4mMwAiDI6cqA7CuA7HHmdlIA)